# Python Jupyter - Relative path between packages

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, relative-path

There are quite a few questions regarding python relative paths, but I have not found anything for the following situation:

```
src/
    __init__.py
    notebook.ipynb
A/
    __init__.py
    foo.py
B/
    __init__.py
    bar.py
```

I'm trying to import in notebook.ipynb:

```
from A.foo import Foo
```

which has a subdirectory/subpackage import to make:

foo.py

```
from ..B.bar import Bar
```

I'm getting a ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package.

If I had only a few files, I would try to hack a solution using sys and os. However, I got quite a few in deeper directories and am looking for a more elegant way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I saw that you said you are looking for a more elegant solution than using sys, however using sys gives a solution for this example.

foo.py:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('..')

from A.foo import foo
```

notebook.ipynb

```
import sys
sys.path.append('..')

from B.bar import Bar
```